# AngularJS loading more than once when using nested states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm getting a `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.` when trying to use nested views on a Ruby on Rails and Angular app. I'm using ui-router and angular-rails-templates.

Angular config and controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'templates']);

app.factory('categories', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        categories: []
    };
    o.get = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/categories/' + id + '.json').then(function (res) {
      return res.data;
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider', 
    '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
    });
    $stateProvider
    .state('home.categories', {
        url: '/categories/:categoryId',
        templateUrl: 'categories/_categories.html',
        controller: 'CategoriesCtrl',
        resolve: {
            category: ['$stateParams', 'categories', function($stateParams, categories) {
                return categories.get($stateParams.categoryId);
            }]
        }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  }]);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($state) {
  $state.transitionTo('home.categories');
});

app.controller('CategoriesCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'categories',
    'category',
    function($scope, categories, category) {
        $scope.posts = category.posts;
    }
]);
```

And the templates:

_home.html (`*edited:` deleted `body` and `ng-app` from this template, following @apneadiving advice, and used the right path, as pointed by @Pankaj Now, views are rendered properly, but the `'loading more than once'` persists)

```
  <a href="#/home/categories/1">Category One</a>
  <a href="#/home/categories/2">Category Two</a>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
```

_categories.html

```
<ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!--<rails head>-->
<body ng-app="app">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

What is happening is that the state 'home' appears and when I click on the links, the URL changes but nothing else happens. And I get the message that Angular is being loaded more than once.

**EDITED**: Got it working. It was a `<%= yield %>` conflict in another part of the app that should have nothing to do with the Angular part.

Comment: you sure you only have one ng-app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are defined the child states, you need to change your URL's to `/home` as they are child of `home` state, the URL gets inherited from parent state.

```
<a href="#/home/categories/1">Category One</a>
<a href="#/home/categories/2">Category Two</a>
```

Comment: thanks! that worked to  render the nested view. however I'm still getting the 'warning' about loading angular more than once. I followed @apneadiving advice and deleted `body` from `_home.html`. `ng-app` is used only once, on `application.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt boot your app in a template like you do.

Add the `ng-app` to your html's `body` and remove it from the template (actually your template shouldnt bear the body either)

Comment: thank you! I changed that, but no luck with the 'loading more than once' thing.

Comment: then you have another ng-app somewhere, it should not appear in any template

Comment: nope =/ I'm working only with `_home.html` and `_categories.html` for now... I now have the `ng-app` on `application.html.erb`.

Comment: And you only have one single `ng-app` in `application.html.erb` ?

Comment: Yes. I just have `body` and `ui-view` tags. `ng-app` is in `body`. I looked at the server request and, besides now rendering the view correctly, there is this  `´RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/categories/.json")`. Maybe that is what is being loaded, but I don't know how...

Comment: depending on how you configured your routes, maybe the routing error ends up serving the base template again leading to the angular issue. This is why its best to isolate the api serving data (in a `/api` for instance) so you can handle routing errors properly

Comment: I understand. Actually, everything was working perfectly till I tried the nested views. I'm getting data from `categories/:id.json` (`categories#show`). That is what the ng-controller supposed to be using. =/

Comment: I doubt it, you are targeting `"/categories/.json"` so you miss the `id`

Comment: OK. So if you doubt what I say, I don't know how to explain that I am getting the data, the views are rendering correctly now after I changed the links. But OK, you doubt it.

Comment: :) look at the error, your browser tries to get data from `"/categories/.json"` and not something like `"/categories/1.json"` so the route is badly formatted and cant render the show